# How to properly format a SD card on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: partitioning, format, sd-card

I have a 16GB Micro SD Card that for some reason only shows 1.1GB. I tried several tips and forums on how to fix my problem but I'm not having much luck. There's a separate partition on it that I tried to remove but it won't let me format it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use gparted to delete this 1.1 partition and create a new one.

You can install gparted by running:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

You can also format the new partition there.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure **sdb** is your sd card! (with `lsblk`)
*If you enter the wrong device, you could accidentally overwrite all your data anywhere!*

Just zero out the drive.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
```

Or use any disk utility of your choice. Deleting the two partitions and creating a single new partition will do.

Comment: You probably should add `bs=4096` or something like that for a better performance of `dd` by increasing the block size that gets written at once. As it currently stands, you operate on single bytes.

Comment: @ByteCommander Yup. forgot it : )

Comment: I tried the terminal command that you suggest but all I got was "dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sdb’: Permission denied".

Comment: Overwriting the contents of an sd card is not at all the same as formatting it.

Comment: @Pointy It is not about formatting. you should have read the question before down voting